# Multi-threading using vectors causing runtime errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I am working on a assignment where I need to calculate the frequency of prime numbers from 1 to 10 million. we are to do this by taking variable U (which is 10 million) and dividing it into N parts and have multiple threads calculate the frequency of prime numbers, we must try this with different values for N and observe our proccessor ticks and time taken to calculate. I thought the best way to do this is with vectors, and the professor recommended it. however when I run my code, I get two run-time errors, first one being "Vector Subscript out of range" and the second one "standard C++ Libraries out of range && 0" . i checked to see if i went out of bounds in the vectors some where but it does not seem that I have. below is the code. thanks for taking a look and any feedback is greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#define MILLION 1000000
using namespace std;
using std::for_each;
void frequencyOfPrimes(long long upper, long long lower, long long* freq)
{
    long long i, j;
    *freq = upper - 1;
    for (i = lower; i <= upper; ++i)
        for (j = (long long)sqrt(i); j>1; --j)
            if (i%j == 0) { --(*freq); break; }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    clock_t ticks = clock();
    long long N = 5;
    long long U = 10*MILLION;
    long long F=0;
    long long d = U / N;
    vector<thread> tV;
    vector<long long> f, u, l;
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            l.push_back(2);
            u.push_back(d);
        }
        else {
            l.push_back(u[i - 1] + 1);
            u.push_back(u[i - 1] + d);
        }
    }
    l[N - 1] = U;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tV.push_back(thread(frequencyOfPrimes, u[i], l[i], &f[i]));
    }

    for_each(tV.begin(), tV.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));

    ticks = clock() - ticks;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        F = f[i] + F;
    cout << "Frequency is " << F << endl;
    cout << "It took " << ticks << " ticks (";
    cout << ((float)ticks) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds)" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {`  Did your compiler give you a warning on this line concerning the different `int` types being used?  And you should use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` so as to give you details on what the illegal subscript you're using is (using `at()` will throw `std::out_of_range` exception).  When you fix those errors, then you go back to using `[ ]` to access the vector items.

Comment: The 'f' vector is used but not initialized. You dereference f, by using f[i], and *f[i], etc, which is not fine since f is empty. You must call f.resize(N) before using it, or initialize with the value you want (the same way you did for vectors 'u' and 'l')

Comment: @johand, thanks, this was the solution i was going crazy trying to figure it out. thanks alot.

Comment: Rather than using `vector::at()`, try to find a diagnostic mode of your compiler, it should give you additional runtime checks against common errors. They depend on you running the code in a debugger though, which is an even more important skill you need to learn.